# Display number countdown before game starts c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

My windows 8 game was created in c# and does what its supposed to do but instead of it automatically starting when the user clicks the level a countdown will begin. Like 3...2...1...Go! type of thing. But the numbers would come up and fade out.

here is the storyboard for the fading numbers

```
 <Storyboard x:Name="FadeOut">
    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="Image1">
 <Storyboard/>
```

This xaml code does work for the fading out but how can I do it so the numbers gradually come on then fade away in a span of 4 seconds I guess for each of them to display and officially start the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FadeOutThemeAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.fadeoutthemeanimation.aspx) is a built-in storyboard which probably isn't flexible enough for what you want, but it's pretty easy to create your own (especially if you use Blend).

Here's one I mocked up that seems to get close to what you want.  It could use some tweaking, particularly on the fade-in/out timings, but you can modify those just by playing with the [KeyTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.keytime.aspx) properties in the XAML.

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="Fader">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="4"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="3"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="2"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="1"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="Go!"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```